# Unity c# POST to PHP not working

Tags: c#, php, database, unity-game-engine, post

I'm having a really annoying problem with php. With c# I send variables to php, and I want php to save it into my database. But the `$_POST` in php is empty.
In Unity I did a `Debug.Log` of the variables I am sending to php right before it sends to see if it works, and the variables are there. BUT in php when I echo the `$_POST`, it returns nothing, it's empty and in the database it adds emptiness.

**Update:**
I added an if statement on the php code to see if the post variables are empty, say, it's empty, if they are not empty, update them in the database. BUT it keeps saying the variables are empty. I need to finish this project in 3 days and this is the only problem that I have to fix and I'm done, please help.

c#:

```
public IEnumerator replaceData(string toggle1Post, string toggle2Post, 
                                string toggle3Post, string toggle4Post,
                                string toggle5Post, string toggle6Post)
 {
     WWWForm form = new WWWForm();


     form.AddField("toggle1Post", toggle1Post);

     form.AddField("toggle2Post", toggle2Post);

     form.AddField("toggle3Post", toggle3Post);

     form.AddField("toggle4Post", toggle4Post);

     form.AddField("toggle5Post", toggle5Post);

     form.AddField("toggle6Post", toggle6Post);

     WWW www = new WWW(parkingURL, form);

     yield return www;

     Debug.Log(www.text);
 }
```

php:

```
//Make the connection_aborted
$conn = new mysqli($server_name, $server_username, $server_password, $dbName);

//Check connection_aborted
if (!$conn)
{
    die("Connection Failed. ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
else 
{
    //echo("Connection Success" . "<br>");
}

$parkingName1 = "Bus Gate";
$toggle1Post = $_POST['toggle1Post'];

$parkingName2 = "Pepsi Gate";
$toggle2Post = $_POST['toggle2Post'];

$parkingName3 = "Watson";
$toggle3Post = $_POST['toggle3Post'];

$parkingName4 = "PVA";
$toggle4Post = $_POST['toggle4Post'];

$parkingName5 = "Gardens";
$toggle5Post = $_POST['toggle5Post'];

$parkingName6 = "Omar Mohsen";
$toggle6Post = $_POST['toggle6Post'];


if ($toggle1Post != "" || $toggle2Post != "" || $toggle3Post != "" || $toggle4Post != "" || $toggle5Post != "" || $toggle5Post != "")
{
    $sql1 = "UPDATE parking SET Toggle = '$toggle1Post' WHERE gateName = '$parkingName1'";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql1)) echo " Updated " . $toggle1Post;
    else echo "notUpdated: " . mysqli_error($conn);

    $sql2 = "UPDATE parking SET Toggle = '$toggle2Post' WHERE gateName = '$parkingName2'";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)) echo " Updated " . $toggle2Post;
    else echo "notUpdated: " . mysqli_error($conn);


    $sql3 = "UPDATE parking SET Toggle = '$toggle3Post' WHERE gateName = '$parkingName3'";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql3)) echo " Updated " . $toggle3Post;
    else echo "notUpdated: " . mysqli_error($conn);


    $sql4 = "UPDATE parking SET Toggle = '$toggle4Post' WHERE gateName = '$parkingName4'";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql4)) echo " Updated " . $toggle4Post;
    else echo "notUpdated: " . mysqli_error($conn);


    $sql5 = "UPDATE parking SET Toggle = '$toggle5Post' WHERE gateName = '$parkingName5'";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql5)) echo " Updated " . $toggle5Post;
    else echo "notUpdated: " . mysqli_error($conn);


    $sql6 = "UPDATE parking SET Toggle = '$toggle6Post' WHERE gateName = '$parkingName6'";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql6)) echo " Updated " . $toggle6Post;
    else echo "notUpdated: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
else
{
    echo "The variable is empty ";
}
```

Update 2:
I tried the same code on another computer with unity version 5.4.1f1 and it worked there, on my computer I'm on version 2017.3.0f3 and it does not work.

Comment: It looks like you missed the part of the PHP script where you're doing anything with $_POST. Can you show that here as well?

Comment: You know you need to refer to keys in the `$_POST` superglobal, e.g. `$_POST['toggle1Post']`, right? Variables like `$toggle1Post` won't be automatically defined.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Sorry I forgot to post the first part of the php code, I just updated it